# How to display total number of nested objects inside an input text field (Firebase Realtime Database) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code below was able to display the total number of objects inside an input text field. Now, how will I display the total number of objects if it is nested? The image below shows the content of my realtime database. I want to get the total number of "donation" that has a "donationStatus" "Declined"

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
var output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
            
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(), 'Users');
const dbQuery = query(dbRef, orderByChild('status'), equalTo('Pending'));

get(dbQuery).then((output1) => {
    console.log(Object.keys(output1.val()).length);
    output1.forEach((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: It's much more likely that we can help if you do debugging yourself, and share the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: There is no `status` or `pending` fields shown in the question so that code may not work at all. It’s a good idea to include structures as *text*, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure ensuring relevant fields are included (so we know they exist)